Ceiling fan light stays dimly lit
I have recently noticed that when I turn the light on my ceiling fan off, one of the bulbs stays partially on.  I replaced the wall switch without success.  There is no dimmer switch, and no remote.  Any help is appreciated thank you in advance!!

is it separate fan/light switch

Only one of the bulbs? Are they all the same type?

If you are using LED bulbs: Many now use a phosphor to convert some light frequencies from those easy for an LED to deliver to those desired for overall effect. This phosphors, like those of an old CRT television, can continue emitting light for a while after they have been excited, resulting in a low glow from the bulb despite power having been completely removed.
It's mostly harmless, unless you really need immediate absolute darkness.
